# Move an existing layer into a group layer using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, group-layer

I have a map object and I am trying to move an existing layer from that map object into a newly created group layer in the same map object.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")
mp = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr = mp.listLayers()[0]
group = mp.createGroupLayer("New Group")
```

I cannot find any documentation describing this. On the [Map Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm) page it says this:

> The moveLayer method will move a layer within a map and **also into and out of group layers** in the same map. The move_layer and reference_layer must reside in the same map. A layer cannot be moved from one map to a different map even within the same project. Use addLayer, addLayerToGroup, or insertLayer instead.

But it doesn't describe how. I'd rather not use `addLayerToGroup`and then use `removeLayer` (to remove the original layer) as this seems inefficient.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? It seems as if "moving" would not keep the original, so your objection is moot.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use addLayerToGroup... see attached example code...

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mp = aprx.listMaps()[0]
#mp = aprx.listMaps("Specific Map Name")[0]  Use this instead if you have multiple maps in your project

if "MyGroupLayer" not in [lyr.name for lyr in mp.listLayers()]:
    mp.createGroupLayer("MyGroupLayer")

lyr_to_move = mp.listLayers("My Layer Name")[0]
group_layer = mp.listLayers("MyGroupLayer")[0]

# Use this to move layers (but not into a group layer)
#mp.moveLayer(group_layer, lyr_to_move, "AFTER")

# Use this to move a layer into a group layer
mp.addLayerToGroup(group_layer, lyr_to_move, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
```